# How to use params without showing in url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**controllerA from state A**

```
$state.go('account.accountRegister', {accountType: $stateParams.accountType, acName: acName})
```

**State defined in app.js**

```
.state('account.accountRegister', {
    url: '/:accountType/register',
    params: {accountType, acName},
    views: {
        'mainView@':{
        templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
        controller: 'registrationController'
    }
}
})
```

**controllerB from state B**

```
console.log($stateParams.acName); // is getting undefined
```

How to use `acName` in the controller without showing in the url part of the state?

Comment: try givinng default values to state params. `params: {accountType: null, acName: null}`

Comment: if I mention `null` I am loosing its value.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution

```
        .state('account.accountRegister', {
                url: '/:accountType/register',
                params: {
                    acName: {
                        value: 'defaultValue',
                        squash: false
                    }
                },
                views: {
                    'mainView@':{
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
                        controller: 'registrationController'
                    }
                }

        })
```

For more info on `squash` property of the `params` object:

https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider